# Enlarging image when tapped ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-gallery

I have an app that implements horizontal gallery. In my story board when a job (cell in a tableview) is tapped it will redirect and display job details. In my Job Details Scene : I have index 0 : for company logo and name, salary and the position. in index 1 : i have the horizontal gallery - I created a scrollview programmatically and created a imageviews inside the scrollview. 
Here's how I created the scrollview and imageviews:

```
else if (indexPath.section == 1)
{
    [self getImages];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.scrollView];

    return cell;
}

- (void)getImages
{
    mutableURLstorage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSInteger noOfImages = (unsigned long)[mutableStorage count];
    NSString* strURL;

    //store image_paths (company and branch) in a mutable array
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfImages; i++)
    {   
        NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *oneMinLater = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:1444];
        NSString *hmac_body =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%lld\n%@",METHOD,[@(floor([oneMinLater timeIntervalSince1970])) longLongValue],CONTAINER_PATH] ;

        // below get different string with shaA diagest
        const char *cKey2 = [KEY cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        const char *cData2 = [hmac_body cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC2[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey2, strlen(cKey2), cData2, strlen(cData2), cHMAC2);
        NSData *HMAC2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC2 length:sizeof(cHMAC2)];
        NSString *HMACStr = [[HMAC2 description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
        HMACStr = [HMACStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
        HMACStr = [HMACStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?temp_url_sig=%@&temp_url_expires=%lld", URLstorage, CONTAINER_PATH, HMACStr, [@(floor([oneMinLater timeIntervalSince1970])) longLongValue]];

        [mutableURLstorage addObject:strURL];
        [imagesArray addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]]]];
}

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(ITEM_WIDTH, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    _pgCtr = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenRect.size.height-30, 320, 36)];
    _pgCtr.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    int numberofPage=ceil((float)[imagesArray count]/3.5);
    _pgCtr.numberOfPages= numberofPage;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*numberofPage, pageSize.height);

    int imgCurrentX = 10;
    for (UIImageView* image in imagesArray) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgCurrentX, 0, 70, 70)];
            imageview.image = (UIImage*)image;
            [imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:imageview];
            imgCurrentX = imgCurrentX+80;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to display the horizontal gallery but the images are all for thumbnails.
Now I implemented this code in my viewDidLoad to determine whether an imageview is tapped:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapAction:)]];
```

In my **singleTapAction** method i am using [LeveyPopListView](https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView) to display the enlarged iamges.

```
- (void)singleTapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)singleTap_
{
    [self createLeveyPopList];
}

- (void)createLeveyPopList
{
    NSString *jobs_name = @"JOBSD";

    if(self.lplv.delegate != nil)
        return;

    self.lplv = [[LeveyPopListView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The following jobs are located here:" options:imagesArray jobName:jobs_name handler:^(NSInteger anIndex) {
}];
    self.lplv.delegate = self;
    [self.lplv showInView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

What I did in my pop up is redisplay the original image gallery (the one in job details scene) but the images are enlarged. My app is successfully implementing the horizontal image gallery. Now my problem is, for example image 2 is tapped, I need to display the image 2 first instead of displaying image 1 first.
I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to change the size of your ImageView that contains the image, like so:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
 // Use this Sender property to your advantage
   [yourImageViewName setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
}
```

Of course, adjust the coordinates to however you would like them. You can also play around in the image view's settings in IB to make sure that your picture does not become distorted upon enlargement.

Now, you could also add tags to your images and enlarge the image view based upon which tag you've pressed. If you want to go that route instead, let me know and I'll post the code. I hope I helped!

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. In my case, the images that I store in my imagesArray are from the server. Now the number of images depends on the number of images returned to me from the server. Now my question is, if I am to use the 'tags' how will i be able to tag each image when I am getting them from the server?